# WebJarAssets cannot locate jQuery.min.js

Tags: jquery, scala, playframework, webjars

My setup used `org.webjars.webjars-play.2.5.0` with Scala Play 2.5. I was using couple of WebJars libraries for different purposes and ended with 2 `jquery.min.js` files located in 2 directories, `target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/jquery` and `target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/jquery/dist`.

When I accessed the index web page, an exception `[IllegalArgumentException: jquery/jquery.min.js could not be found` was thrown by `<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery/jquery.min.js"))"></script>` even though the file existed at `target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js`. I tried different path `lib/jquery/jquery.min.js` to locate the script but unsuccessful. However, when `dist/jquery.min.js` is used, it can find the script but it is the version I wanted.

How do I configure to help WebJarAssests to locate the `jquery.min.js` in `target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib/jquery`? How do I stop other WebJars from loading a different versions of `jquery.min.js` into my project? Thanks

Meanwhile, I am using `<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("lib/jquery/jquery.min.js")"></script>` to get things going.

*Update 1*

Current setup,

```
class ApplicationController @Inject() (
  val webJarAssets: WebJarAssets,
  val silhouette: Silhouette[CookieAuthenticatorEnv],
  ...
) extends AuthController {...}

@(webJarAssets: WebJarAssets, ...)(implicit messages: Messages)

GET         /webjars/*file          controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
```

Comment: I use exactly that (initial) code. Does your controller look something like `class MyController @Inject() (implicit webJarAssets: WebJarAssets, ...` and your view signature something like `@(...)(content: Html)(implicit webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)`, and route like `GET /webjars/*file          controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)`?

Comment: My `webJarAssets` is not `implicit`. I injected WebJarAssests via Guice and it worked for other JS libs except for jQuery.ja. Is that a problem?

Comment: jquery should not be any different. Perhaps worth posting your view signature, script jquery reference, controller signature, route and the relevant line from build.sbt - might make it easier for people to help.

Comment: I have updated my post with additional code and view. I suspect there was a name collision with jQuery because there are 2 jQuery libs. I remove it the second jQuery in `build.sbt libraryDependencies` i.e.  `"org.webjars.bower" % "bootstrap3-dialog" % "1.34.4" exclude("org.webjars.bower", "jquery")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the regular Play Static Asset stuff + sbt-web to use the `target/web/web-modules/main/webjars/lib` files, or you can use the `WebJarAssets` thing.  More details in [the docs](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#play2).

To use `WebJarAssets`, instead of:
`webJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js")`

Try:
`webJarAssets.locate("jquery", "jquery.min.js")`